# phpMyAdmin wrong results when using CONCAT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, concatenation

I'm using version `4.1.13` of phpMyAdmin. Please consider the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `testcol` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`testcol`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`testcol`) VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3');
```

The following query seems to return wrong results:

```
SELECT CONCAT(testcol), testcol FROM `test` WHERE 1;

CONCAT(testcol)   testcol
---------------   -------
             31         1
             32         2
             33         3
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a PMA bug? Running the query directly in MySQL's command-line client returns the expected results.

The results should be:

```
CONCAT(testcol)   testcol
---------------   -------
              1         1
              2         2
              3         3
```

Comment: what do you mean by CONCAT function here, normally you use it with two arguments

Comment: I tried your code. Its working fine as you expect.. May be it would be bcoz of version problem I think.

Comment: Update the version of phpMyAdmin since there is no problem with your code.

Comment: @ktaria I used CONCAT with a single argument for simplicity's sake, to compare MySQL's result with PMA's result. CONCAT with multiple arguments has the same problem, returns garbage.

Comment: @LucasHenrique This version, 4.1.13 is the latest stable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently version 4.1 requires MySQL version 5.5+

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(testcol), testcol FROM `test` WHERE testcol=1;
```

result:

```
CONCAT(testcol)   testcol
---------------   -------
             31         1
```

Comment: did you check my answer or not

Comment: Same thing - CONCAT(testcol) still returns the wrong value of `31`

Comment: @Dude Are you trying to cast to a string?

Comment: @h2ooooooo No, I'm only trying to concatenate a string like "teststring" with the values for each row. `SELECT CONCAT("teststring", testcol) FROM test WHERE testcol=1` returns `74657374737472696e6731`